# Magento catalog price rule apply percentage discount but it's rounding up to 21% and 22%

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, discount

I am applying a catalog price rule to reduce certain items by 20%, however some items are showing a reduction of 21%, 22% and 23% which is shown on the sale tag. We are using the theme 'Harbour' which I presume is applying the sale tag. The code that calls this is the following:

```
<?php echo MAGE::helper('ThemeOptionsHarbour')->getProductLabels($_product, 'sale'); ?>
```

Obviously I don't want this happening. I have already tried changing Calculation Settings-> Apply Discount on Prices - Including Tax to Excluding Tax but this didn't seem to work.

Here are a few screen shots of my settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried different settings like applying with or without tax?

Comment: Yes I have tried changing Apply Discount on Prices - Including Tax to Excluding Tax but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you update the question with how the `sale tag` is calculated? Sounds like some custom piece of code

Comment: I have updated it now.

Comment: Could you add the code that prints the percentage?

Comment: I have just spoken to the theme developers and they have assured me that it is a default Magento functionality, rather than the functionality of the theme.

Comment: same problem here with Magento ver. 1.9.2.4
If I apply 20% reduction, prices are reduced by approx. 21%. This only happens when other reductions are active.
The 20% reduction has highest priority (lowest priority number) and should cancel all further price rules. any idea?